# Recognized, calibrated test points for a rangefinding function?

Tags: data, point, distance, coordinates, georeferencing

I'm trying to find out if there are scientifically accepted calibration points to measure the effectiveness of a geodetic distance finding function. So far I've been using the listed latitude / longitude coordinates of various airports but I'm not sure where exactly in the airports they're measuring (the control towers?) and its hard to judge my error rate with that unknown.

I thought it might be better if there were points that were a known distance apart - such as where the Prime Meridian crosses Greenwich or the compass rose at the Hoover Dam?

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.